# Can i use indexOf() on an object?

Tags: javascript, database, react-native

When i call `checkInList()` in my React Native app I get the error:

> `TypeError`: Cannot read property `indexOf` of undefined

The `myList[]` appears to be an object not an array, so i don't know if that's why `indexOf` isn't working? What can i do about it? I need this to run quite fast and quickly check. Are there any alternatives?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    myList: []
  }
}
// get string list from DynamoDB and set it locally to myList
assign() {
  this.setState({myList: userData.data.getlist.mylistfromDB}); 
}
// Then check if my string is in the list i just set 
checkInList() {
  if (this.state.myList.indexOf("xyzabc") > -1) {
    // In the list!
  } else {
    // Not in the list
  }    
}
```

My list: 
[image: See List here]

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. It's `undefined` when you call `indexOf`. Why? No way to tell; we can't see what `userData.data.getlist.mylistfromDB` actually is.

Comment: myList is a list of strings. I've verified that i'm getting a list of strings, so it's populated

Comment: The console is not a reliable way to debug as it can show results after they've loaded, e.g., async. `myList` is `undefined` when you're using it--there's not enough information here to diagnose why. You would get a different error if it was an object instead of an array--it's neither, it's `undefined`. A screenshot of who-knows-what isn't diagnostic--it may be for *you*, but we can't see over your shoulder.

Answer (score 0):

`myList` is an array and indexOf should work with strings. Your data is probably not being loaded before it's checked. Maybe `mylistfromDB` is returning undefined. Check if your functions are being executed in the right order because I assume your data loading call is async and you also need to be careful with the lifecycle events. If you try to render something that is still being loaded after `componentDidMount`, it could go wrong too.

Comment: myList is a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Probably `userData.data.getlist.mylistfromDB` is returning `undefined`

You can add a check before calling the `setState` function -

```
assign() {
  let data = userData.data.getlist.mylistFromDB;
  this.setState({myList: data ? data : []}); 
}
```

Comment: myList[] is populated with a list of strings

Comment: The logs in the console are a bit tricky. Try debugging using your editor with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the error if your setState data i.e myList is undefined. So check once, if its `undefined` you cant use indexOf in that.

You can do something like :

```
  assign() {
  let dataToBeadded = userData.data.getlist.mylistFromDB;
  this.setState({myList: dataToBeadded == undefined ? dataToBeadded : []}); 
}
```

Comment: myList[] is populated with a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() is a property of Array or list in JavaScript which indicates the index of the element specified within the parameters.And Object stores the values in key value pair thus, indexOf cannot be used on objects to get the index.

```
var a = {1: "1", 2: "2"}
>> a.indexOf(2)
>> Uncaught reference error

var b = [1,2,3]
b.indexOf(2)
>> 1
```